# Define methods in child component to use ref hook - React native functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 2 functional components and, let say `Parent` and `Child`. Then I have a method `doThis()` inside `Child` component to invoke some functionality such as state update in the child. `Child` component is inside the parent and I need to use that as a reference using `useRef()` hook and call the `doThis()` function.

The implementation goes like this.

```js
//Component Parent
function Parent(){
 const child= useRef()
 if(child.current){
   child.current.doThis()
 }
 return( <Child ref={child}/>)
}
```

```js
function Child({ref}){
 
// Don't know how to define
 function doThis(){
   //Do some task
 }
 return( <View/>)
}
```

I have seen a section called **Methods** in react-native documentation. Ex: `scrollToIndex()` in `FlatList`

So how to define such methods using functional components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forwarding refs to DOM components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Example of such component:

```
import { TextInput as TextInputNative } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const TextInput = React.forwardRef(
  ({ ...props }, ref) => (
    <TextInputNative
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
    />
  )
);

export default TextInput;
```

Here how I use my component later in code:

```
<TextInput
  ref={inputRef}
/>
```

To create a ref, I use `useRef(null);`